# Why would bitmap outperform vector, as3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

**Why would bitmap outperform vector?**

My Flash is for a large Kiosk, with rich media requirements and must function accurately as a counter. I want to keep everything vector for scalability.

When I did a simple FPS test, I noticed my Bitmap version performed perfectly, and the all vector file was noticeably slower.

**PLEASE EXPLAIN**
• vector performance
• what graphic standards I can apply
• solutions for using vector

---

**KIOSK TEST ANIMATION**
[alt text http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/daemonfps.jpg](http://www.ashcraftband.com/myspace/videodnd/daemonfps.jpg)

---

**RESULTS**
• only text and bitmap perform well, not vector
• background and clouds OK, but more layers slow it down

Comment: Well, you still have to render the output. With bitmaps it's just a blit (memory copy), while with vectors it's actual calculations and generation of pixels. Bitmaps will always be faster than vectors with pixel-based display technologies.

Comment: @Max I strongly disagree. I would _absolutely_ expect vector to outperform bitmap in Flash.

Comment: @Michael: Why so? I understand that Flash is expected to be an excellent vector graphics renderer, but it's still an extra step to take.

Comment: @Micheal - Sorry buddy, but bitmaps outstrip vectors with speed every time. If you spawn 1000 spinning things from you library that is a vector, you'll notice the machine chug - use bitmaps and you won't notice a framerate drop.

Comment: I stand corrected ( http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=87849 ). As always, the answer is "it depends."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its really quite logical when you get your head around what a vector is.

A vector is a visual representation of the computer plotting many points on the screen and joining the dots and colouring it in. This is a the reason why vectors look good scaled up as well as down.

A bitmap as your probably aware - in flash is regarded as pixel data. Something thats just picture stuff.

When the screen renderers vectors, at every screen redraw it must plot and map and recreate the vector - each time working it out.
With bitmap, - well, its a picture and therefore saves all that computing power trying to redraw complicated objects and plot 100's of points.

You caching everything as vector, you will not notice a difference in the slighest. Anything you've drawn on the stage - check the 'cache as bitmap' checkbox, and any new item produced in the code and added as a child, `cacheAsBitmap = true` on every visual thing.

There is a great little trick that should work a treat here.

You can still use your vectors. However, when adding them to your stage, check the 'cache as bitmap' checkbox underneath the display settings in the properties panel.

in the code you can write

`myCloud.cacheAsBitmap = true`

That property is available for every visual object.

This works best when the objects you have on the stage are doing simple things like spinning and fading - it tends to not be as effecient when performing movieclip nested animations and similar stuff, as of course, the object will still need to be redrawn at every frame. Although you will still see a big improvement.

---

here are some urls on the from googling 'as3 cache as bitmap'

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/bitmap_caching_03.html

live docs for displayObject - you'll see it 3 down in the first table.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html

Comment: only set cacheAsBitmap to true when the Sprite does NOT rotate, continually scale or have alpha set to  < 1 otherwise the image has to be recached each time there is a change which is costly.

Comment: @Allan This is an important point, often overlooked. When you transform a graphic object (expect for x or y translation), the cached bitmap is no longer valid and has to be recalculated. If you're changing your graphic, say, every frame (or very often, as vague as that is), cacheAsBitmap will make things worse, not better.

Comment: Don't attempt to use the advice in this answer without noting Allan's comment!

Comment: Have you got a reference so I can read up on this? I've always kinda  experienced the opposite.

Comment: @Glycerine, thanks. CasheAsBitmap gave my vector animation full performance. For moving things across the stage 'without' alpha or scaling, I know it works great.

Comment: No problemo! - I'm still pushing for the proof of a perfomance drop if the cached object isn't static but as long as you fixed your problem the world is a happier place. And its sunny in Glasgow today! Wonderful world it is.